# Solving this simple separable differential equation gives 2 answers?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Straight to the point.

The equation is:

$ \frac {dy}{dx} = y^2 $

If we create the constant on the RHS after integrating, as such:

$ -y^{-1} = x + c $

We yield the final equation:

$ y = \frac {-1}{x+c} $

But if we create the constant on the LHS, as such:

$ -y^{-1} + c = x $

We get the following equation:

$ y = \frac {-1}{x-c} = \frac {1}{c-x}$

Are these the same? Are there different constraints on the behaviour of the constant? I'm a little confused and I hope someone can point out the obvious, if anything.

Comment: You're just replacing $c$ with $-c$. The constant can be negative or positive (or zero)

Comment: Thanks, should have noticed this before!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both "equalities" we can let $c=-k$ where $k$ is an arbitrary constant like $c$
and we get $\frac{-1}{x+c}=\frac{-1}{x+k}=\frac{1}{(-k-x)}$,
the right one is equal to $\frac{1}{-(k+x)}=\frac{-1}{k+x}$ and since $k$ and $c$ are both arbitrary constants and have no specific value they are both equivalent

Comment: Thank you, I noticed this afterwards but nice to have it confirmed.